# Handle KeyboardInterrupt in the shell if no script is running

Tags: python, keyboardinterrupt

Is it possible to handle KeyboardInterrupt in the shell if no script is running?

The background of my question is the following:
I use python to send commands to a motor controller via a socket connection. The function sends a target position of a motor to the controller and immediately returns, i.e. before the motor actually reaches its target position. Now it can happen that a user enters a wrong position and wants to interrupt the motor motion as quick as possible. This could be done by typing stop() which sends a stop command to the controller. But it would be more intuitive and faster if the motor could be stopped by pressing Ctrl+C.
Is there a way to let python execute a function by pressing Ctrl+C while no script is running?

I know how to handle the KeyboardInterrupt exception or the signal.SIGINT within a running script, but could not find any hints on how to solve my goal.

I would be very grateful for any help!

Comment: Adding a system-level hook that overrides the default functionality of Ctrl+C is not a good idea.  You would be better off modifying your Python code such that the a movement holds the script open until the movement is complete.  You can use a context manager to capture KeyboardInterrupt and issue `stop()`.

Comment: I agree that changing the default Ctrl+C functionality is a bad option. The problem with keeping the script open is that I want to be able to execute other functions while a motor is moving.

Comment: are you on Linux, Mac or Windows?

Comment: @James: I am on Linux

Answer (score 1):

If the controller can handle having multiple connections to the socket, you can launch an entire new process that makes use of the `keyboard` module to listen for `ctrl+c` and then have that process send the stop command to controller.

First install the keyboard package from pypi

```
pip install keyboard
```

Create a file to listen for `ctrl+c`:

```
# file named 'wait_stop.py
##########################

import keyboard

# code here to establish connection to controller

def wait_stop():
    keyboard.wait('ctrl+c')
    print('sending stop signal')
    # function that sends stop signal here...
    # ...
    # call wait_stop again to continue listening.
    wait_stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wait_stop()
```

Now you can launch the process in a separate shell via:

```
python wait_stop.py
```

As long as the `wait_stop` process shell is NOT the active window, hitting `ctrl+c` will cause send the `stop()` function to the controller.  If the window is active, it will also kill the `wait_stop.py` process.

Comment: This approach seems the most promising so far! The controller can unfortunately only handle one socket connection. But I think I can put the keyboard.wait(...) in a thread and then use the same socket connection as in the main thread. And as far as I understand, due to the use of the GIL in threading I don't have to worry that overlapping communications with the controller mess things up.

Comment: I noticed that keyboard.wait() requires root privileges. So to use it in a thread I guess I would need to run the main thread as root, which I don't want. Is there an alternative which doen't require root?

Comment: You may want to look into a different key bind handler like Autokey [https://code.google.com/archive/p/autokey/]

Answer (score 0):

KeyboardInterrupt send `SIGINT` signal (code 2).

So instead of hitting CTRL+C you could send KeyboardInterrupt with `kill -2 <pid>`.

To display your program pid use `os.getpid()`.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to kill the program. I want to be able to invoke some action within python (i.e. send a command to the controller) by pressing Ctrl+C